# For Loop with Try Except Continuing Until End of Loop Range

Tags: python

I have written a for loop to retry a `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` statement until it finds the image. For some reason the code loops through all 20 cycles even though the image is found in the first few tries. Can anyone see the problem?

```
for x in range(0, 20):  
    try:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("PPTTTW.png", region=(537, 682, 93, 325)):  
            print("found")
            str_error = None
    except Exception as str_error:
        pass

        if str_error:
            sleep(0.5)  
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Catching something as broad as *any* exception, only to ignore it completely, is a bad idea. Surely there is a *specific* exception type you know is safe to ignore; you should only be catching that.

Comment: Setting `str_error` to `None` doesn't do anything useful, as the code that checks its value isn't reached if you manage to make the assignment.

Comment: What is the for loop for if you do not use `x` in it?

Comment: @intedgar Limiting the number of retries, presumably. `x` could be replaced by `_` to indicate we never actually care about particular iteration, just that there aren't more than 20 of them.

Comment: @chepner But nothing changes from the first to the last iteration. So I don't see the sense. If it didn't find it in the first iteration, it will also not find it in a later one, or am I missing something?

Comment: What changes is that `x` increases as `locateOnScreen` fails to find whatever it is looking for. The loop exits  when `x == 20`, or when the `break` statement is reached. Whether or not it *can* raise an exception, or change its return value without changing its arguments, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to write this is to put the `break` statement directly in the `try` block, where it is only reached when an exception is *not* raised.

```
for _ in range(20):  
    try:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("PPTTTW.png", region=(537, 682, 93, 325)):  
            print("found")
            break
    except Exception as str_error:
        logging.warning("Got %s, retrying...", str_error)

    sleep(0.5)
else:
    logging.error("Never found")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the loop to continue after finding it, then use break in the corresponding if statement:

```
for x in range(0, 20):  
    try:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("PPTTTW.png", region=(537, 682, 93, 325)):  
            print("found")
            str_error = None
            break
    except Exception as str_error:
        pass

        if str_error:
            sleep(0.5)  
        else:
            break
```

But are you sure you need a for loop even? Because I don't see you using `x` in there at all.